# Configure AWS cloudfront for serving signed url from s3 bucket

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5

i've have a folder named `private` in my s3 bucket and the contents in that folder only accessed by authorised user (ie Public read access is disabled).

So i am generating sigened url's for accessing one of the object in that folder it works fine.

Here is the signed URL format

```
s3-<region>.amazonaws.com/<folder>/<imagename>??X-Amz-Content-Sha256=.......
```

Also i have created cloudfront distribution for the above s3 bucket for better performance.
here is the cloudfront url `xxxxjjjj.cloudfront.net`

So how can i serve my signed url with this cloudfront distribution??

When i try with this url

`xxxxjjjj.cloudfront.net/<folder>/<imagename>??X-Amz-Content-Sha256=.......`

I will get access denied error,i think this is  not the right way to deliver the s3 signed url content with cloudfront distribution.

Using php laravel framework

Answer (score 5):

Signed URLs for CloudFront use a different format and different credentials than signed URLs for S3.

Read [Serving Private Content through CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html).

There is a [laravel-url-signer](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-url-signer/blob/master/README.md) on GitHub or you can write your own code from [this example in the CloudFront docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreateURL_PHP.html).

For testing your CloudFront and S3 settings, you can use [`aws cloudfront sign ...`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/sign.html) in aws-cli to generate a test signed URL.

Comment: I've already generating signed url's using php sdk but when i the base part  ie( `s3-<region>.amazonaws.com` replaced with `hhsdjf.cloudfront.net`) its give an access denied error

Comment: Changing the host component of the URL is not how this works.  CloudFront signed URLs are *entirely* different, generated by different code, and include `&Key-Pair-Id=...` in the query string -- they do not use `X-Amz-Credential` and do not use `AWSAccessKeyId`.

Answer (score 1):

There is an example for what you are asking using PHP SDK in this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/cloudfront-signed-url.html

and here's the equivalent code in Larave (5.3) using custom policy:

```
public static function signedUrl($resourceKey) {
    //$resourceKey = 'videos/example.mp4'
    $baseUrl = 'https://xxxxjjjj.cloudfront.net';
    $fullUrl = $baseUrl . '/' . $resourceKey;
    $expires = time() + 300;
    $customSigningPolicy = <<<POLICY
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Resource": "{$fullUrl}",
            "Condition": {
                "DateLessThan": {"AWS:EpochTime": {$expires}}
            }
        }
    ]
}
POLICY;

    // CloudFront Signed Urls
    /** @var CloudFrontClient $cloudFront */
    $cloudFront = \AWS::createClient('CloudFront');
    $url = $cloudFront->getSignedUrl([
        'url' => $fullUrl,
        'policy' =>  $customSigningPolicy,
        'key_pair_id' => 'YOUR_KEY_PAIR_ID',
        'private_key' => '/path/to/your/cloudfront-private-key.pem'
    ]);

    return $url;
}
```

P.S. I found a mistake in the aws example, since they used the $resourceKey as the Resource value in the policy which is not woking, what worked with me is to use the full url of the file.

Their code:

```
$resourceKey = 'videos/example.mp4';
$customPolicy = <<<POLICY
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Resource": "{$resourceKey}",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {"AWS:SourceIp": "{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}/32"},
                "DateLessThan": {"AWS:EpochTime": {$expires}}
            }
        }
    ]
}
POLICY;
```

What Worked:

```
$resourceKey = 'videos/example.mp4'; // or $resourceKey = 'videos/*'; or $resourceKey = '*';
$fullUrl = $baseUrl . '/' . $resourceKey;
$customPolicy = <<<POLICY
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Resource": "{$fullUrl}",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {"AWS:SourceIp": "{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}/32"},
                "DateLessThan": {"AWS:EpochTime": {$expires}}
            }
        }
    ]
}
POLICY;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easiest way to generate cloudfront Signed URL.
There is a [cloudfront signed URL signer](https://github.com/dreamonkey/laravel-cloudfront-url-signer) on GitHub, edit the config and use it.

1. The package can be installed via Composer:

   **`composer require dreamonkey/laravel-cloudfront-url-signer`**

2.The configuration file can optionally be published via:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Dreamonkey\CloudFrontUrlSigner\CloudFrontUrlSignerServiceProvider"
```

3. URL's can be signed with the sign method:

   **`use CloudFrontUrlSigner;`**

   **`CloudFrontUrlSigner::sign('https://myapp.com/resource');`**